# How to return multiple values when using SELECT EXISTS in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT r.id FROM Rules r INNER JOIN rule_t c on c.id=r.rule_t.id 
INNER JOIN user u on u.id = r.user_id
WHERE u.fmnum='2813'
AND c.name='default') ::int
```

Is there a way I can modify this so that I get two values back, the INT from the EXISTS method, and r.id?

I know that I can change the query so that I remove the EXISTS method... if the sub select returns anything at all, then I know the record exists... but I'm just wondering if its possible to do the above.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I'm testing the following code in a new query window in pgadmin3...

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT TRUE, r.id
   FROM   rules  r
   JOIN   rule_t c on c.id = r.rule_t.id 
   JOIN   user   u on u.id = r.user_id
   WHERE  u.fmnum = '2813'
   AND    c.name = 'default'
   );
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias LINE 2: (
>           ^ HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

**EDIT 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT TRUE, r.id
   FROM   rules  r
   JOIN   rule_t c on c.id = r.rule_t.id 
   JOIN   user   u on u.id = r.user_id
   WHERE  u.fmnum = '2813'
   AND    c.name = 'default'
   ) AS x;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you know that the right way to do this is by getting the value from the subselect, what are you really asking?

Comment: I'm asking if I can return two values, one from EXISTS and one from subquery.  Some consumers of the method may want just the boolean from Exists() vs. others who would want both.  The more I can do here, the less I have to do in the methods that call this sql query.

Comment: You can return the value in a subquery and then derive the exists value from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 AS does_exist, r.id
FROM   rules  r
JOIN   rule_t c on c.id = r.rule_t.id 
JOIN   user   u on u.id = r.user_id
WHERE  u.fmnum = '2813'
AND    c.name = 'default'
LIMIT  1;  -- may or may not be needed.
```

This does what you seem to be asking for: you get two columns. But you get *no row* if nothing is found.

If you want a row, even if nothing is found, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT sub.t_id IS NOT NULL AS does_exist, sub.id
FROM  (SELECT 1) x  -- dummy to guarantee 1 row
LEFT JOIN (         -- LEFT JOIN is crucial
    SELECT r.id
    FROM   rules  r
    JOIN   rule_t c on c.id = r.rule_t.id 
    JOIN   user   u on u.id = r.user_id
    WHERE  u.fmnum = '2813'
    AND    c.name = 'default'
    LIMIT  1        -- may or may not be needed.
    ) ON TRUE;      -- join condition is always true
```

Or, simpler / faster:

```
SELECT 1 AS does_exist, r.id
FROM   rules  r
JOIN   rule_t c on c.id = r.rule_t.id 
JOIN   user   u on u.id = r.user_id
WHERE  u.fmnum = '2813'
AND    c.name = 'default'

UNION  ALL
SELECT 0, NULL
LIMIT  1;
```

Comment: Hm.. I just copied and pasted your code but... I'm getting an error message saying that the subquery in FROM must have an alias.. Please check out Edit 1 in my post

Comment: @dot: The alias for the subquery was missing. And my explanation was slightly incorrect, which is fixed, too.

Comment: k.  i guess we posted around the same time. I just added an Edit 2... which is kinda similar to your new post.

Comment: I like it!  Very simple and self documenting

Comment: The only thing that would be cool is if I could still get 0 if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @dot: I added solutions for that.